# Код не отображает группы в запросе SQL, показывает NULL

Tags: sql

```sql
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 18 and 30 
        THEN "Группа 1"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 31 and 45 
        THEN "Группа 2"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 46 and 60 
        THEN "Группа 3"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) > 60 
        THEN "Группа 4"
    END as customer_group_name
    , p.product_group_name
    , count(p.product_group_name) as cnt
FROM orders o
JOIN customers c
    ON o.customer_id = c.customer_id
JOIN orders_product op
    ON o.order_id = op.order_id
JOIN products p
    ON op.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 18 and 30 
        THEN "Группа 1"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 31 and 45 
        THEN "Группа 2"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) between 46 and 60 
        THEN "Группа 3"
        WHEN timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt) > 60 
        THEN "Группа 4"
    END
    , p.product_group_name
ORDER BY count(p.product_group_name) DESC;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Comment: значит case не выполняется и возвращает `NULL`. проверьте для начала без группировки, что возвращается то

Comment: в целом все банально, дифф возвращает отрицательное значение, поскольку первый аргумент заведомо больше второго, так что case всегда null

Comment: Добавил бы `ELSE timestampdiff(...)` к своему CASE - сразу бы увидел проблему...

Comment: Про ELSE Согласен. В четвертой строке CASE  написал просто ELSE "60+" , но на выходе отображается только эта группа

Группа 4 Продукты 1598
Группа 4 Часы 1591
Группа 4 Одежда 1582
Группа 4 Напитки 120

Comment: Про NULL Согласен, Поменял местами CURDATE  и  birth  теперь отображается только первая и последняя группы

Comment: Не удаляйте специальные символы в начале и в конце, который вам добавляют в код запроса, без них код в вопросе показывается без форматирования, читать его не удобно так. А по сути вопроса - сделайте сначала выборку, где выведите `CURDATE()`, `birth_dt` и `timestampdiff(YEAR, CURDATE(), c.birth_dt)`, да посмотрите, что выводится вообще.